# Write var in Angular: See which array is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, angularjs, select

I have a json array. I can see the item in one *select*. When I click on one item, a new *select* is create with - if there are - subarray items.

[HERE](http://plnkr.co/edit/4FyIk367QzCd4ThBk0Tw?p=preview) can see what I am talking about.

All works fine, but I am not able to display info about the selected item. 
How can I do? Because in internet I've found that you can do it writing the ng-model of the selection. But if I write:

```
<span>{{select.id_1}}</span>
```

I see just the ID of the selected item.

Thank you in advice!!

Comment: You can access your selected item by using select.id_2 inside your controller. This is because you have ng-model="select.id_2" on the 2nd select menu. Then, use $watch to check for changes to this value which will allow you to fire a function to lookup the selected item by ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ng-model` will contain the `value` of the selected option. So you will have to manually work out / fetch the right object depending on the value. One way to do what you want would be to go through the list and match up the id, assign that to a variable and use that instead.

I've updated your [plunkr code here](http://plnkr.co/edit/NNAcdFU7ZG24ido83BtA?p=preview).

Essentially, added:

```
$scope.selectedProduct = {};
$scope.selectedLot = {};

....    
$scope.selectedProduct = $scope.list.products[i];

....
$scope.selectedLot = $scope.Subarray[i];
```

This picks the item from list and subarray and assigns them so you're holding the selected object.

Comment: This is what I was looking for! Now, this is for a table that I'm doing. In fact the rows contain the two selection above. I will add also a button for ADD new line, so with new selection. I've tried to iterate, but of course it doesn't work.... In this update http://plnkr.co/edit/8bOxIW2JJIhRUGCuVMzx?p=preview you can see that in the script.js i've added new code (i made comments). I've created one array to include all the info, one function to add new line and one function to delete line. But of course it doesn't work....... what I am doing wrong?

Comment: @panagulis72 sorry, I am not sure what your'e trying to do; are you trying to create a new array that holds all selected items? i.e. when you click *add*, it goes into `allInfo` array and you can add/select multiple items, and then remove it from that array?